# DirectX getting texture size wrong

Tags: c++, animation, directx, textures, sprite-sheet

I am getting started with DirectX and struggling to render 2 animated sprites at once. I turn the spritesheets into textures and then set the frameCount for them using its aspect ratio as a guide

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    texture2D->GetDesc(&desc);

    m_width = desc.Width;
    m_height = desc.Height;
```

These are the 2 spritesheets, as you can see, one of them has 4 frames and aspect ratio of 4:1 whereas the other one has 3 and respective aspect ratio [image]

Now it seems like when I assign the texture to my sprite class, my Manager assigns the correct texture (or `ID3D11ShaderResourceView`), but it gives the size values from the other one, which results in them animating the wrong way (the first one animates in 4 steps whereas the second one animates in three).

This code gets the texture

```
Texture* ResourceManager::GetTextureByName(char* textureName)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)m_textures.size(); ++i)
    {
        ResourceTexture* resourceTexture = m_textures[i];
        string resourceTextureName = resourceTexture->GetName();

        //Bit that matters
        if(!strcmp(textureName, resourceTextureName.c_str()))
        {
            return resourceTexture->GetTexture();
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Is `texture2D->GetDesc` not working like I intend it to? Any directions are greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is how i set up the textures (right before getting their width and height)

```
//Just modifying the texture name to the right format
wstring tempName(fileName);
m_name = string(tempName.begin(), tempName.end());
//Modifying texture name (From original loaded textures names)
int pos = m_name.find_last_of("/");
if(pos >= 0)
{
    m_name = m_name.substr(pos + 1, m_name.length());
}
m_name = m_name.substr(0, m_name.find_last_of("."));

//load the texture
result = CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, fileName, NULL, &m_texture, NULL);
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your code that creates and assigns textures, not with `GetDesc`.

Comment: @VTT I've been looking over this for a few days and still haven't found a clean way to fix it. In the edit i add the code that creates the texture